# How does handshaking takes pace in ejabberd server

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks, ejabberd-saas

I have just started using ejabberd as a messaging server.
Now I have read that TCP connections follow the handshaking method for setting up 
the connection, and I was wondering that how ejabberd follows the 
handshaking method whenever any client say Pidgin client sends a connection 
request.

It's probably a very basic question but after giving in much efforts in trying to find it, I haven't got much success.

Can anyone please explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd handles "handshaking" (that is stream/STARTTLS/SASL negotiation) exactly as described in [RFC6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120). This is implemented in [xmpp_stream_in](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/xmpp_stream_in.erl) module.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I read the rfc link provided by you and it cleared most of my doubts. Just the thing that it is mentioned there in the steps for making the connection under section 1.3 that the second step is making the TCP connection and as far as I know TCP connection setup itself is preceded by a three way handshake.And if this is true then why to go for TLS handshaking too?

Comment: Pretty confusing question :/
Because TCP handshake doesn't include TLS handshake, LOL?